# webkit css3 3d stacking order issue

Tags: css, 3d, webkit

I'm trying to create 'calendar'-like flip animation with css3 3d.
Although it looks great in firefox, in google chrome stacking order is all messed up, it looks like somehow z-indexes have changed.

Here is jsfiddle of my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/qaxfs6pe/

Here is bare html:

```
<div id="calendar">
      <div class="page">
        <div class="front"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300"></div>
        <div class="back">YOU GOT CAGED</div>
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        <div class="front"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300"></div>
        <div class="back">YOU GOT CAGED</div>
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        <div class="front"><img src="http://www.placecage.com/400/300"></div>
        <div class="back">YOU GOT CAGED</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And here is scss that i have which is paired with autoprefixer which I omitted for readability purposes:

```
$w:400px;
$h:300px;
#calendar{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:$w;
  height:$h;
}
.page{
  width:$w;
  height:$h;
  position:absolute;

  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transition:transform 2s;

  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipped{
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(180deg);
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.page > div{
  backface-visibility: hidden;

  width:$w;
  height:$h;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; 
  background:rgba(230,230,230,1);
}
.front{
  z-index:2;
}
.back{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For elements that are in the same node, chrome treats later ones as if they have a higher z-index than the previous element even if it is not so. I has something to do with how chrome establishes a stacking context and also explains why preserve-3d is not required in some instances where Firefox would require it to display correctly.

When I ran into the same problem with a digital clock implementation, I had to change the z-index to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the lack of a 3D container. It allows the browser to render the 3D content properly. By example, if you add:  `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to `#calendar`, chrome will understand that all its `.page` children are part of the same 3D environment and the Z-axis will be rendered properly.

In your current example, every page is its own 3D environment so the browser can't really give the result that you want.

Hope that helps!

http://jsfiddle.net/qaxfs6pe/2/